# Android app: custom listview with image

Tags: android, user-interface, listview

I am relatively new to development of Android apps. I have bought some books on Android development which got me started in developing simple apps.

Now, I want to start building an app that has more functionality. Part of this app consists of a ListView containing about 100 rows. Each row should contain a little image (from remote URL) of a cover of a book and furthermore it should contain the title of the book and the publication date. Tapping on the row should bring up a new Activity containing all details of the movie.

I already have found out how to retrieve the underlying data from a remote web service using JSON.

Right now I am focusing on the GUI.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could give me some tips/code samples of this type of GUI!

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 1):

this is a good tutorial that shows how to write custom listview

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/